# NgClick binding issue inside ionic modals

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I cannot bind any clicks inside my modal. The modals is defined in my controller:

```
$scope.fooBar = function() {
    alert("FOO!");
};

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/withdrawal.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.cashoutModal = modal;
});

$scope.lists = [
    { foo: "CLICK ME 1"},
    { foo: "CLICK ME 2"}
];
```

The modal view is:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Richiedi un bonifico</h1>
    <button ng-click="fooBar()" class="button button-clear button-primary fixed-bar-pos"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="list in lists">
            <div class="weddingListItem" ng-click="fooBar()">
                <span class="title">{{list.foo}}</span>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see by clicking the static button or any of the dynamically generated list items the function *fooBar* should fire, instead nothing happen, no errors in console, no alerts.

[image]

The modal is working and the view is rendering as intended, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <ion-modal-view ng-controller="ModalController">
        <ion-header-bar>
          <h1 class="title">Richiedi un bonifico</h1>
          <button ng-click="fooBar()" class="button button-clear button-primary fixed-bar-pos"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="list in lists">
              <div class="weddingListItem" ng-click="fooBar()">
                <span class="title">{{list.foo}}</span>
              </div>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/dwk1v0ey/)**